# How to create loop to download multiple NAM model projections

Tags: r, loops

I need some help writing a loop to download the list of selected model projections. I am new to the data science world and I struggle with loops. Below I have posted what I have tried so far with no luck. I have included the initial download link. The ideal end goal would be to have all those model projects stacked in a raster brick.

URL: https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_nam_na.pl?file=nam.t00z.awip3200.tm00.grib2&lev_10_m_above_ground=on&var_UGRD=on&leftlon=0&rightlon=360&toplat=90&bottomlat=-90&dir=%2Fnam.20220511

The section "awip3200" is where the list of models should be looped through. ("awip3203", "awip3206", "awip3209"... etc). I have also attached the code where it works for one model downloard.

Thanks!

```
#Loop
mod.list <- c(00, 03, 06, 09, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48, 51, 54, 57, 60, 63, 66, 
              69, 72, 75, 78, 81, 84)

for(i in 1:seq_along(mod.list)) {

  url_ucomp[[i]] <- ("https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_nam_na.pl?file=nam.t00z.awip32" , mod.list[[i]] , ".tm00.grib2&lev_10_m_above_ground=on&var_UGRD=on&leftlon=0&rightlon=360&toplat=90&bottomlat=-90&dir=%2Fnam.20220511")

wind_u[i] <- download.file(url_ucomp[[i]], here("data", "wind_u.grb"))

wind_u[i] <- here("data", "wind_u.grb") %>% 
  raster()

}

#single model download
url_ucomp_00 <- ("https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_nam_na.pl?file=nam.t00z.awip3200.tm00.grib2&lev_10_m_above_ground=on&var_UGRD=on&leftlon=0&rightlon=360&toplat=90&bottomlat=-90&dir=%2Fnam.20220511")

wind_u_00 <- download.file(url_ucomp_00, here("data", "wind_u_00.grb"))

wind_u_00 <- here("data", "wind_u_00.grb") %>% 
  raster()

plot(wind_u_00)
```

Comment: I am getting an error: `wind_u.grb is a grib file, but no raster dataset was successfully identified.`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas strange when I run this code for just one model prediction it works fine.  I also added this code to the above post.                                                                                       
     ```url_ucomp_00 <- ("https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_nam_na.pl?file=nam.t00z.awip3200.tm00.grib2&lev_10_m_above_ground=on&var_UGRD=on&leftlon=0&rightlon=360&toplat=90&bottomlat=-90&dir=%2Fnam.20220511")

wind_u_00 <- download.file(url_ucomp_00, here("data", "wind_u_00.grb"))

wind_u_00 <- here("data", "wind_u_00.grb") %>% 
  raster()

plot(wind_u_00)```

Answer (score 0):

The following code successfully downloads all files. The following changes were made.

- `mod.list` must be a character vector, otherwise `00` is the number `0` and the link is wrong;
- I have replaced the download directory `"data"` by `"Temp"`;
- the downloaded filenames are `"widn_u_??.grb"`, with `"??"` replaced by the values in `mod.list`.

```
library(here)
library(dplyr)
library(raster)

mod.list <- c("00", "03", "06", "09", "12", "15", "18", "21", "24", "27", 
              "30", "33", "36", "39", "42", "45", "48", "51", "54", "57", "60", 
              "63", "66", "69", "72", "75", "78", "81", "84")

gribstring <- "wind_u_%s.grb"
wind.u <- vector("list", length(mod.list))

for(i in seq_along(mod.list)) {
  url_ucomp <- paste0("https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_nam_na.pl?file=nam.t00z.awip32" , mod.list[[i]] , ".tm00.grib2&lev_10_m_above_ground=on&var_UGRD=on&leftlon=0&rightlon=360&toplat=90&bottomlat=-90&dir=%2Fnam.20220511")
  gribfile <- sprintf(gribstring, mod.list[i])
  download.file(url_ucomp, here("Temp", gribfile))
  #
  #wind.u[[i]] <- here("Temp", gribfile) %>% raster()
  #
}
```

The last loop line is commented out because it throws an error.

```
here("Temp", "wind_u_00.grb") %>% raster()
```

> Error in .local(.Object, ...) :
> C:\Users\ruipb\Documents\Temp\wind_u_00.grb is a grib file, but no raster dataset was successfully identified.

> Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  :
> Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.

Comment: thank you! Strange the .grb to raster conversion works fine for one file